# can't write dbf file

Tags: python, dbf

stuck with create dbf file in python3 with dbf lib.

im tried this -

```
import dbf
Tbl = dbf.Table( 'sample.dbf', 'ID N(6,0); FCODE C(10)') 
Tbl.open('read-write') 
Tbl.append() 
with Tbl.last_record as rec: 
     rec.ID = 5 
     rec.FCODE = 'GA24850000'
```

and have next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\operator\Desktop\2.py", line 3, in <module>
    Tbl.open('read-write') 
  File "C:\Users\operator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\dbf\__init__.py", line 5778, in open
    raise DbfError("mode for open must be 'read-write' or 'read-only', not %r" % mode)
dbf.DbfError: mode for open must be 'read-write' or 'read-only', not 'read-write'
```

if im remove 'read-write' - next:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\operator\Desktop\2.py", line 4, in <module>
    Tbl.append() 
  File "C:\Users\operator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\dbf\__init__.py", line 5492, in append
    raise DbfError('%s not in read/write mode, unable to append records' % meta.filename)
dbf.DbfError: sample.dbf not in read/write mode, unable to append records
```

thats im doing wrong? if im not try append, im just get .dbf with right columns, so dbf library works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error.
In the older versions of the dbf module, I was able to write dbf files by opening them just with
`Tbl.open()`

However, with the new version (dbf.0.97), I have to open the files with
`Tbl.open(mode=dbf.READ_WRITE)`
in order to be able to write them.

Comment: can you give me example, how you open file and add rows? im just pass write error, but cant insert row, new error - dbf.FieldMissingError: 'ID:  no such field in table'

Answer (score 2):

here's an append example:

```
table = dbf.Table('sample.dbf', 'cod N(1,0); name C(30)')
table.open(mode=dbf.READ_WRITE)
row_tuple = (1, 'Name')
table.append(row_tuple)
```